# Unique factorization domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I am confused about showing the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}] $ is a UFD?

I understand to show that for all non-zero units you must show they factor into irreducible elements and that they must all be associates of each other although I do not know how to prove this because to disprove it is easy simply showing a counterexample.. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  In fact it's [norm-Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Norm-Euclidean_fields)

Comment: Show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ has class number 1, which is easy using the Minkowski's bound.

Comment: Or you can show it is a Euclidean domain for the norm as a euclidean function.

Comment: How would you show it is a Euclidean Domain?